# How to pass along an identifier with an item in ListView?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-listview, identifier

I have a ListView which contains EMPLOYEE_NAME from a DB table EMPLOYEE.  Some employees may have the same name, which means I could have duplicated items in the ListView.

What would be the best solution for identifying which item (employee) the user selected?  I know that the event onItemClick returns the View associated with the selected item and doing a ((TextView) view).getText() gets me the employee name.

But what would be the solution for passing the row id along with the employee name?  Should I extend TextView to include the row id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onItemClick contains a long parameter called id, which is what you would want to use:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

So, if you are using a `CursorAdapter` the only thing you have to do is making sure that the ID row in the database is called `_id`.

If you are using other kind of adapters, say `BaseAdapter`, you **have to** override the `getItemId` method, where you will return the ID of the employee.

Comment: Oh, that's what BaseAdapter.getItemId() is for.  It just so happens that I had built a custom adapter. Thanks.